# Text is moved when focus in input(text) in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, arabic

I'm building a website called [**AppStore-Icons**](http://appstore-icons.com/?lang=ar) which contain a search box, the content of the search box is moved up/down **on focus** like this :

[image]

I noticed this problem only in **Chrome** and only in the **Arabic** version of the website, I've tried to fix it by adding this CSS :

```
.search_box input[type="text"],
.search_box input[type="text"]:focus {
   line-height: 15px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   font-size: 45px;
   height: 65px;
}
```

but nothing of it worked, how could it be fixed ??

[Link to the Arabic version of the website](http://appstore-icons.com/?lang=ar)

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Are you sure that is not a search element (`input[type="search"]`)?

Comment: it's a search box, but i'm using `<input type="text">` in my HTML @SverriM.Olsen

Comment: It appears to have something to do with the font size. Right-click the element, inspect it, and then untick the `font-size`. That appears to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the following CSS :

```
.search_box input[type="text"]{
    overflow: hidden;   //so the text won't move
    padding-bottom: 0;  //so the text won't be cut
    font-size: 34px;    //so the text will be contained in the input border
}
```

The real problem was that the **Arabic font** which I'm using has large height, and the problem shows **on focus** because of the **Caret** (the blinking writing cursor) whose height is equal to the character height of the font (only in chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this on `.search_box input[type="text"]`

```
line-height:65px;
```

Comment: i'm already using `.search_box input[type="text"]` in the website, and the code in the question is just simplified